# trouble accessing value from jsonArray

Tags: json

I am using  gson to parse json
I have a com.google.gson.jsonArray

```
    JsonObject object = jelement2.getAsJsonObject().getAsJsonObject("fields");   
    JsonArray jArray = (JsonArray) object.get("entity_facets");

    Output of jArray is :
    [{"count":4,"entity":"Com","Company":[{"sector":"Communications","ticker":"VZ","entity":"Verizon","type":"BCap","instance":[{"count":1,"entity":"Verizon (VZ, Fortune 500)"}]},{"sector":"Technology","ticker":"AAPL","entity":"Apple","type":"BCap","instance":[{"count":1,"entity":"Apple (AAPL, Fortune 500)"}]},{"sector":"Communications","ticker":"T","entity":"AT&T","type":"BCap","instance":[{"count":1,"entity":"(T, Fortune 500)"},{"count":1,"entity":"AT&T"}]}]}]
```

Now I want to extract the array under Company from jArray

Answer (score 1):

Add like this

```
JsonObject jobject = jArray.get(0);
JsonArray CompanyArray = (JsonArray)jobject.getAsJsonArray(Company);
```

you will get the company array from jArray.